# Adding a persistent volume claim to an application using Openshift (OKD) CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift, persistent-volumes, okd

I am trying to learn my way around the Openshift (OKD) environment that I am used to working in, but rather than performing certain tasks within the UI, I am trying to learn on the CLI instead.

Forgive me if someone somewhere has already asked/ received an answer on this issue, but I am wondering if anyone can give me a super simple example of how to create a new persistent volume claim for an application using the CLI?

I have looked through the developer docs on Openshift and have even tried to problem solve using the CLI help option, but nothing I am doing seems to work.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using the `oc set volume` command. Options depends on needs. Consider reading free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ which covers simple examples of doing it using CLI.

Comment: This was incredibly SUPER helpful! I learned a ton from this eBook and it provided great visibility and understandable explanations for my current issue plus resolving other administration issues I am dealing with in the CLI. Forget two birds one stone, Multiple birds, one big ass boulder!!! thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Normally three steps need to perform to add storage to a pod/container in openshift.

1. create a PV - interface between real storage and openshift
2. Create PVC - interface between pv and pod/container
3. mount pvc to pod by declaring voulme and mount points in DC/POD config.

you can perform all these three steps through CLI easily.